# key value relation on Skip List (DXL/DOORS)

Tags: skip-lists, ibm-doors

I am trying to find the same login id users in database.

First I put every user to skiplist then I want to compare one by one. My question is how can i get the key value on Skiplist.

The piece of my code is here :

```
for lUser in userList do {

    string uName = lUser.name
    string uEmail = lUser.email
    string uSys = lUser.systemLoginName
    string uAdr = lUser.address
    outBuf +=  uName sep uSys sep uEmail sep uAdr
    outBuf += "\n"

    // Here I have to add some code, I can put the values but not get again or compare
    // I need some for loop and get every key value
    put(skiplist,count,uSys)
    print count
    print "\n"
    count++
}
```

Could someone give tips for this, I am new on this language. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: NOW IT IS WORKING**

```
    pragma runLim,0
string sep = ";"
string dbName = getDatabaseName
print "\n" "List of doors user in database " getDatabaseName  ": \n\n"
int count = 0
User lUser

Group lGroup
Skip skiplist = create

for lUser in userList do {
  string uName = lUser.name
  string uEmail = lUser.email
  string uSys = lUser.systemLoginName
  string uAdr = lUser.address


  if(null uSys)
  {
    print uName " doesn't have a System Name.\n"
  } else {
    bool flagDuplicate = false
    string nameDuplicate = ""
    string s = ""
    for s in skiplist do {
      if(s == uSys) {
        flagDuplicate = true
        nameDuplicate = (string key skiplist)
        break
      }
    }

    if(flagDuplicate) print "Users '" uName "' and '" nameDuplicate "' have the same System Name (" uSys ").\n"
    else put(skiplist,uName,uSys)

  }
}
```

`pragma runLim,0` this line is for avoiding the execution time warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is this:

```
for lUser in userList do {
  string uName = lUser.name
  string uEmail = lUser.email
  string uSys = lUser.systemLoginName
  string uAdr = lUser.address
  outBuf +=  uName sep uSys sep uEmail sep uAdr
  outBuf += "\n"

  if(null uSys)
  {
    print uName " doesn't have a System Name.\n"
  } else {
    bool flagDuplicate = false
    string nameDuplicate = ""
    string s = ""
    for s in skiplist do {
      if(s == uSys) {
        flagDuplicate = true
        nameDuplicate = (string key skiplist)
        break
      }
    }

    if(flagDuplicate) print "Users '" uName "' and '" nameDuplicate "' have the same System Name (" uSys ")."
    else put(skiplist,uName,uSys)

    print "\n"
  }
}
```

EDIT: I added a check for a blank `uSys`, you can do anything you want there, if you want to just add all the empty ones to a list then print it out at the end that would work too.

This should at least point you in the right direction.

NOTE: I don't have the ability to test this code currently so I apologize if there are any errors or typos. But I think it will get you close enough.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this solution. My purpose is getting the people id from database and if different people has got same id, detect and print them to screen. So I think first I have to put all people to skiplist. After I will start from beginning to end compare everyone by one by. Am I wrong ? Are there any more easy way to do this ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand why different users would have the same system login name. However if you do encounter a duplicate name what do you want to do with it? Are you just trying to build a list of all the unique system login names in the database, or are you trying to print out any of the duplicate names?

Comment: Because some people in the system sometimes register in for twice or some case sensitive problem so in the database there are same loginID users. For example :
login id : ssx101 name : Batuhan BARDAK
login id : ssx101 name : Batuhan Bardak

So when I try to login_id with ssx101 login_id the system cannot decide which user try to connect. Batuhan `BARDAK` / Batuhan `Bardak`
Now I have to take all login_id's and compare and if there is same I have to print that login_id information to screen.

Comment: I updated the answer, I believe this is what you want. Let me know if I can be of any more help.

Comment: Like you said this edit is too much help to me but there is still a problem. I just recognize that sometimes login_id field comes null so there occur a run time error. I change my code like that, you can look my edits but it still doesn't work. Maybe you can show me some way how can i fix this code ?

Comment: Made edits. You can move things around and add in any other code you want but this should do it.

Comment: Now its okay, I take a execution time error but i added this line of code at the beginning `pragma runLim,0`. Everything works fine, thanks a lot

Comment: I need a help about one more issue you can check this link if you have time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20239531/run-dxl-script-on-the-background-command-line-dxl-doors