# run DXL script on the background (command line) : DXL/DOORS

Tags: cmd, ibm-doors

I am trying to start a dxl script with command line. But i am getting lots of warnings and errors.

When I try this script on doors gui , it works fine but when i try on this command line without gui, it doesn't.

Here is the image of warnings :

[image]

[image]

Here is the commandline script : 
`"%ProgramFiles%\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.3\bin\doors.exe" -d 36677@bie -u "xxx yyy" -P don -b "d:\workset\mc\addins\Devel\exporterRTF.dxl"`

Why it doesn't work with commandline ? Any help, idea etc is appreciated.

**EDIT :**

this is a link which i try to run : **[myprogram.dxl](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6509308/)**

this is a link which is imported in my running script **[include in myprogram.dxl](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6509314/)**

this is a link which is secondly imported in my running script **[include in myprogram.dxl](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6509320/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other settings you need to run in Batch mode (pulled from the DOORS help):

```
Runs Rational DOORS in batch mode. Rational DOORS starts without the GUI (it suppresses the login screen and the database explorer), runs the specified DXL program, and then stops.
In batch mode you normally need other switches like -user, -password and -project to log in and specify the current project.

The parameter of the -batch switch specifies the file that contains the DXL program that you want to run in batch mode.
```

You probably need a current project specified. Also you may need to add a command at the end of your script to exit DOORS if you don't want the session to stay open.

The errors that you list seem like regular DXL errors, so if you need more assistance than this, you will need to post some of the code.

**EDIT:**

If you put all of the files into one does it run? Another option may be to include the Addins path on your command line. I believe the issue is that the batch mode is not recognizing the included files as part of the same scope.

Comment: I have already read some post from the ibm forum but actually I cannot fix yet. I added my question and add related codes. Any idea, help is appreciated.

Comment: I also tried to include .inc files from command line but the problem is still continue :/ What a weird problem is that. When i try to do in interactive it works, but from command line it doesn't. Also i try to open a program from command line and start script and close the gui again but it also again fails. :/

Comment: Did you try making it one file? Instead of using include files?

Comment: How can i do it one file ? Should i copy completly the .inc files and added on the beginning of the dxl file ?

Comment: Yes, copy in the full text of both inc files in place of where you are including them now.

Comment: Still same problem continue. i use this command in command line: `"%ProgramFiles%\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.3\bin\doors.exe" -d 77@bie -u "Bardak Batuhan" -P don -b "d:\workset\mc_tool_doors\addins\Devel\exporterRTF.dxl"` and like you said i added all included directly to the exporterRTF.dxl . But also my include files are contain some includes so should i do this recursivly for every include ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42413/discussion-between-batuhan-bardak-and-steve-valliere)